# C# XML Serialization int tag value not supplied

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a class that can be serialized. One of the properties is an int, and if a value isn't supplied for the field, the tag is still present but with a zero value, because an int cannot by null of course.

The problem i have is that the client who wants to recieve the xml doesn't want to see the tag at all if a value has not been supplied. They do not want to to see the tag with a 0 value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make it an `int?` it will be suppressed when `null`:

```
public int? Foo { get; set; }
```

You can also hide this on your object's API:

```
private int? foo;
public int Foo {
    get { return foo.GetValueOrDefault(); }
    set { foo = value; }
}
public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() { return foo.HasValue;}
```

where `ShouldSerialize*` is a pattern recognised automatically by `XmlSerializer`

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the [DefaultValue(0)] attribute to the property, the value is only serialized if it differs from that value:

Short example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Serialized));
        Serialized s = new Serialized();
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, s);

        Serialized s2 = new Serialized { Value = 10 };
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, s2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Serialized
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The first serialized object does not have a Value-attribute, where the second one which has a Value other than 0 is written.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that `0` *is* a valid int, so in many cases will suppress a valid value. If the value should never legitimately be zero it is fine though.

Comment: You're right, I haven't consider that. It's definitly a drawback as a common solution for the problem. But it won't require an additional property (although you can apply your solution using a custom PropertyDescriptor, which also has a ShouldSerializeValue method).